# por qué no me guarda en el arreglo la opcion seleccionada?

Tags: java, netbeans, bucle-for

Buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto pequeño de la universidad en el cual intento poner un arreglo donde al seleccionar una opcion me pida los datos del clientey luego me los muestra, si la opcion ya fue usada debe mostrar un error pero el ciclo se sigue repitiendo aun cuando la opcion ya esta usada y deberia estar guerdada en el arreglo:

```
    public void verificar() {

        for (int i = 0; i < ins.verificar.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ins.verificar[i] + " " + ins.canchas[ubicacion]);
            if (ins.canchas[ubicacion] == ins.verificar[i]) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La reservacion ya existe");
                instalacion();
            } else if (ins.canchas[ubicacion] != ins.verificar[i]) {

                cliente = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del cliente ");
                horas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la cantidad de horas que desea alquilar "));
                Date fec = new Date();

                String strDateFormat = "hh: mm: ss a dd-MMM-aaaa";
                SimpleDateFormat objSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
                fecha = objSDF.format(fec);

                calculoPrecio(horas);
                ins.verificar[i] = ins.canchas[ubicacion];
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su total de la cancha " + ins.canchas[ubicacion] + " es: " + total + "\n"
                        + "en el horario " + fecha + " \n" + "a nombre del cliente: " + cliente);
                instalacion();
            }

        }

    }
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: puede colocar las inicializaciones de los arreglos.